# Is it possible to retrieve data from Sqlite (and CoreData) without a UITableView - Swift 3

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, swift3

I have a database that has about 1000 records (sqlite).
I want to access theses records without using a `UITableView` (index) but by the key (i.e name) of the an attribute.

I am having great issues as all tutorials are using the `index.row`

Is this logic wrong? Should I be using something else?

**EDIT:**

***I have managed to do this so far:***

```
  // MARK: - Fetched results controller

var predicateString = "some string"


var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Anatomy> {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack()
managedObjectContext = coreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext


let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Anatomy> = Event.fetchRequest()
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Event", in: self.managedObjectContext!)
fetchRequest.entity = entity

myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "nameEng contains[c] %@", predicateString)
fetchRequest.predicate = myPredicate

fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sortID", ascending: false)

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
_fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

do {
    try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
} catch {
    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
    // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
    let nserror = error as NSError
    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
}

return _fetchedResultsController!
}

var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Anatomy>? = nil

func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
   //do sth
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    //do sth
}
```

***But I am having trouble in this now:***

```
   let object = self.fetchedResultsController......  as! Event //cannot cast this to Event and don t know how to get the values now.... 

            print(object.buttonTag)
//this is where indexPath comes and "messes" things around for me....
```

Comment: there is no need for UITableView to retrieve data from database

Comment: @rokjarc is there a tutorial you can recommend? I haven't found anything on google... but then again I could be searching for the wrong thing...

Comment: Those two things are unrelated. A UITableView shows information - the information you decide to give it. The fact that the information comes from a database or not is irrelevant. You can show this information the way you want, you don't have to put it in a table view.

Comment: @EricAya thanks. As I said, all tutorials use indexPath or use an array to display the data. What I want is to get the entity.attribute based on say a predefined string... hence the question about logic.... Is it correct or should i do something else?

Comment: @GeorgeAsda: i can't recall any of them but you can share a link of the one you are using and i'm sure we can make it work without a tableview.

Comment: @rokjarc here is a link: https://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated         it is an old one that I am trying to convert and understand....

Comment: this is gonna take a while so i can take a look at it later when i come home

Comment: @rokjarc Thank you.

Comment: If you are using CoreData, you can specify a *predicate* for your fetch request which will then return only the object(s) that match the predicate.  See [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate) and the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) for details of the appropriate syntax.

Comment: If you want to access a specific property of your NSManagerObject, you can do so using Key Value Coding. The Key would be the name of the attribute you are accessing, provided as a string.

Comment: I looked into that and I thought it would be very expensive to perform such a task (predicate through 1000 records each time). Am I wrong in my logic (again?)

Comment: and there are some good questions / answers here on SO. first you should decide if you are going to use sqlite3 or coredata. for reading complete sqlite3 take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341001/how-do-i-retrieve-all-the-rows-from-an-sqlite-table

Comment: I d prefer core data. But then again I'm not an expert and I would happily take up on your advise.

Comment: @rokjarc can you see the edited question please?? Am I doing anything right? or am I doing it wrong (again)?

Comment: i didn't notice the 'swift' tag before, sorry to say i don't really 'speak' it

Comment: @GeorgeAsda I assume you are just trying to get hold of the one object that matches your predicate.  The FRC returns an array objects (even if there's only one - it's an array with one element), which is why you can't cast to Event.  Instead, just access the first element in the array (...fetchedObjects[0]...).  With appropriate casting/optional unwrapping, that should give you the Event that matches your predicate.  But using an FRC in these circumstances is overkill - a simple `executeFetchRequest()` using a fetch with the correct predicate should yield the same results.

Comment: @pbasdf   Ok. Thank you for that. How would you approach this then? Can you add an answer with your suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a tableView, I wouldn't bother with the FRC - a standard fetch should suffice:

```
let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack()
managedObjectContext = coreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext

let fetchRequest = Event.fetchRequest()

let myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "nameEng contains[c] %@", predicateString)
fetchRequest.predicate = myPredicate

do {
    let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Event]
    let myEvent = results[0]
    // Do whatever you need with the Event...

} catch {
    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
    // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
    let nserror = error as NSError
    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
}
```

Comment: thank you. It does work... I had to change to this though: let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Event> = Event.fetchRequest() as your suggestion was throwing an error: ambiguous use of fetchRequest

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use UITableView for your purpose not at all.

Here are some guides I am using

This is tutorial how SQLite could be used with Swift
https://www.raywenderlich.com/123579/sqlite-tutorial-swift

And here you could refer detailed SQLite reference:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/index.htm

Here you can refer specifications sqlite functions while you use them:
https://www.sqlite.org/

Let me know what you need to get further more.
Btw, you need to define your own model classes for each schema in database.
And you should get all columns via sqlite c API.

If you are using Objective-C, its easier to use this API.

I hope this will help you.